# Set output video duration to be the same as the duration of input video1

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am trying to create an output video using two videos. However, among the two input videos "Test1.mp4" has a shorter duration. How can I make the output video duration to be the same as "Test1.mp4"?

```
ffmpeg -i Test1.mp4 -i Test5.asf -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]xstack=2:layout=0_0|w0_h0" -map 0:a -vsync 2 Output2.mp4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For filters which take in multiple inputs, there are some common options to determine filter lifetime. These are the [framesync](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Options-for-filters-with-several-inputs-_0028framesync_0029) options.

You should pad the 2nd input and enable the shortest option.

```
ffmpeg -i Test1.mp4 -i Test5.asf -filter_complex "[1:v]tpad=stop=-1:stop_mode=clone[v1];[0:v][v1]xstack=2:layout=0_0|w0_h0:shortest=1" -map 0:a -vsync 2 Output2.mp4
```